# What are the pros and cons of using distributor per bank vs single bigger distributor on a dohc v8 for example?

Tags: engine, ignition, spark, spark-plug-wires, distributor

early Ferrari 308 models used a distributor per bank that worked on their respective bank , but on later 308s they switched to a single bigger distributor that worked for both banks. What would be the pros and cons of both setups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the play in both causes the timing to drift between the two banks when there are two distributors.

A single distributor with either one or two sets of points is easier to time - especially if you go for an optronic ignition upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Solar Mikes correct +1 .The single distributer must be proportionaly larger in diameter to keep the plug to plug voltage clearances to avoid one cylinder arcing into the next .The total   HT lead length will be longer with the single distributer .